# Two colors in one hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, color, cleveref

As usual writing a few documents. As one can see having too much color and gloss in a document is never good. Therefore having boxes, and a myriad of colors in the hyperlinks is a bad idea. I really like the format `Type (#1)` for my links as seen below. Now my question is

- **Is it possible to make the whole link into a hyperlink, but only color the number?**

I want to have the `equation (1)` format, but only the number should be colored and the whole thing should be a hyperlink. Is this possible?
Also is it possible to do this with custom commands? For the MWE the second hyperlink should read `Format (1)`. To keep it consistent.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,pdfmenubar=false,pdfstartview={FitH},linktoc=all,urlcolor=blue}

\newcounter{foo}

\newcommand{\header}{\paragraph*{\refstepcounter{foo} Format \arabic{foo} }}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\crefformat{equation}{equation~(#2#1#3)}

\begin{document}

\header \label{Format1}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{equation}
x^2 + x + 1 = 0\,. \label{phi}
\end{equation}

\Cref{phi} and \cref{Format1} \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: the statement of the question sounds like you want the link to be even more colorful!  maybe "how to limit color to only part of a hyperlink?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight improvement on Heiko's answer is to customise `\labelformat` instead of `\crefformat`. Then you don't need to redefine all of `\crefformat`, `\crefmultiformat`, `\crefrangeformat` and `\labelcrefformat` to avoid breaking `cleveref`'s multi-reference features:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  pdfmenubar=false,
  pdfstartview={FitH},
  linktoc=all,
  urlcolor=blue,
  linkcolor={},
}

\newcounter{foo}

\newcommand{\header}{%
  \refstepcounter{foo}%
  \paragraph*{Format \thefoo}%
}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\creflabelformat{equation}{#2(\textcolor{red}{#1})#3}

\crefname{foo}{format}{formats}
\creflabelformat{foo}{#2(\textcolor{red}{#1})#3}

\begin{document}

\header \label{Format1}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{equation}
x^2 + x + 1 = 0\,. \label{phi}
\end{equation}

\Cref{phi} and \cref{Format1} \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

`Cleveref` is...clever enough to still make the entire name part of the hyperlink when you use the `nameinlink` package option, even if you customise `\creflabelformat`. (This despite the fact that the `\labelformat` definition looks like it doesn't include the name.)

Answer (score 10):

You are already formatting your links with `\crefformat`. Thus it is easy to add coloring. The linked text is surrounded by `#2` and `#3`. Now the first letter is not auto-detected any more and `\Crefformat` is also needed to get the upper cased form. `Hyperref`'s coloring for inner document links is disabled by `linkcolor={}`.

The example also fixes the issues with counter `foo` and its reference:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  pdfmenubar=false,
  pdfstartview={FitH},
  linktoc=all,
  urlcolor=blue,
  linkcolor={},
}

\newcounter{foo}

\newcommand{\header}{%
  \refstepcounter{foo}%
  \paragraph*{Format \thefoo}%
}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\crefformat{equation}{#2equation~(\textcolor{red}{#1})#3}
\Crefformat{equation}{#2Equation~(\textcolor{red}{#1})#3}

\crefformat{foo}{#2format~(\textcolor{red}{#1})#3}
\Crefformat{foo}{#2Format~(\textcolor{red}{#1})#3}

\begin{document}

\header \label{Format1}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{equation}
x^2 + x + 1 = 0\,. \label{phi}
\end{equation}

\Cref{phi} and \cref{Format1} \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]